# Zsh and TCL Expect Prompt Detection

Tags: regex, automation, tcl, expect

I am trying to detect the user prompt, so that Expect knows what to expect after each command has completed. You can assume that I was heavily inspired by the following code, under the heading: [Is This Really The Prompt I’ve Been Expecting?](http://linuxgazette.net/2013/01/advanced-programming-in-expect-prompt-your-prompts)

Now what I am having trouble with is prompt detection with the use of Zsh. The correct prompt is captured: `[user_scripts]>`, but it does not match against the following:

```
proc check_prompt { id {prompt ""} {wait 0} {timeout 3} } {

# we have to determine the prompt, and we may have to wait first
after $wait;

# find out if the session is responsive
exp_send -i $id "\r";

# process what we get back as a response
if { "$prompt" != "" } {
   # we are looking for a particular prompt to verify
   # this can be changed to allow flexibility if needed
   expect {
       -i $id
       -exact "$prompt\$" {
           # partial or complete prompt matched with anchors
           return [string trim $expect_out(buffer)];
       }

       timeout {
           send_user "\[ERROR\]: Could not match prompt to .${prompt}.\n";
           return -1
       }
   }
} else {
   # use a fairly well-crafted regular expression to find a prompt, and
   # then re-enter this procedure with a verification request
   expect {
      -i $id
      -re "\[\r\n\](\[^\r\n\]+)" {

         # Quick cleanup of our first capture
         set str [string trim $expect_out(1,string)]

         # Double check this prompt response
         return [check_prompt $id $str];
       }

      timeout {
           send_user "\[ERROR\]: Could not determine prompt. Contact script maintainer\n";
           return -1
      }
   }
}
```

}
`

Looking at the debug output of expect, I can see Zsh adding in the color codes, which is what appears to be preventing the match:

> **expect: does**
>   "\r\n%{\u001b[0;31m%}[user_scripts]%1~>%{\u001b[0m%} \r\n"
>
> **match exact string** "(%{\u001b[0;31m%}[user_scripts]%1~>%{\u001b[0m%})$"? **no**

How would I get expect to match against this?

I am using expect version 5.43.0 and unfortunately I cannot update it (corporate constraint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question is trying to match a regular expression, but you're not telling expect to use regex matching:

```
expect {
   -i $id
   -regex "${prompt}\$" {
      return [string trim $expect_out(buffer)];
   }
}
```

---

Hmm, might work if you do this:

```
  -re "\[\r\n\](\[^\r\n\]+)" {

     # transform the capture into a glob-pattern
     set prompt_glob "*[regsub -all {[][?*]} [string trim $expect_out(1,string)] {\\&}]*"

     # Double check this prompt response
     return [check_prompt $id $prompt_glob];
   }
```

And you'll have to change

```
   -exact "$prompt\$" {
       # partial or complete prompt matched with anchors
       return [string trim $expect_out(buffer)];
   }
```

to

```
   -glob "$prompt" {
       # partial or complete prompt matched with anchors
       return "$prompt"
   }
```

And henceforth, you'll expect the prompt with `expect -glob $prompt`

Comment: Updated above. Let me know if you still need more info. The prompt input to the function is blank.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually. The only issue now is that my older version of expect is causing me trouble - bad switch "-inline": must be -all, -nocase, -expanded, -line, -linestop, -lineanchor, -start, or --
    while executing
"regsub -all -inline {[][?*]} [string trim $expect_out(1,string)] {\\&}"

Comment: Works now. The only real downside to all of this is that I have to correct my prompts to go from -re to -gl, but this is a big help. Thank you

Comment: So far this seems much more useful over the previous implementation